# Why when I import spacy package I get 'Logger' object has no attribute 'encoding' in zeppelin?

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin, spacy

Zeppelin (ver 0.8.1) is working on ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.6.8.
I installed spacy (ver. 2.1.1) and it is normally imported by python interpreter from command line.

But when I try to make `import spacy` from zeppelin notebook I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-4434566237091100057.py", line 308, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 16, in <module>
    msg = Printer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wasabi/printer.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.anim = animation if can_render(animation) else animation_ascii
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wasabi/util.py", line 153, in can_render
    string.encode(sys.stdout.encoding or "ascii")
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

What can I do with that?

Comment: This looks like a bug / unideal handling in my command-line printing library `wasabi` – sorry. But I can fix this! It seems like you're logging standard output, so `sys.stdout` isn't what wasabi expects it to be.

Comment: Try `pip install -U wasabi`!

Comment: Ok it works now